# convert string to time in r

Tags: r, time, numbers

I have an array of time strings, for example `115521.45` which corresponds to `11:55:21.45` in terms of an actual clock.

I have another array of time strings in the standard format (HH:MM:SS.0) and I need to compare the two.

I can't find any way to convert the original time format into something useable.

I've tried using strptime but all it does is add a date (the wrong date) and get rid of time decimal places.  I don't care about the date and I need the decimal places:

for example

```
t <- strptime(105748.35, '%H%M%OS') =  ... 10:57:48
```

using %OSn (n = 1,2 etc) gives NA.

Alternatively, is there a way to convert a time such as 10:57:48 to 105748?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the options to allow digits in seconds, and then add the date you wish before converting (so that the start date is meaningful).

```
options(digits.secs=3)

strptime(paste0('2013-01-01 ',105748.35), '%Y-%M-%d %H%M%OS')
```

Comment: apologies if i wasn't clear, I've edited the post to reflect this.  i'm not interested in the date.  i need the decimal places to be kept.